# Use Applescript to create hyperlink in a text item in Numbers

Tags: hyperlink, numbers, applescript

I'm unable to make a `text item` (an iWork container) a hyperlink. The equivalent actions to be performed with the GUI would be:

- Add Text Container
- Modify Text
- Select Text Container, right click and select "add link"

I succeeded in using Applescript with Numbers to create a hyperlink in a cell value. To do this I set the cell value to the `=hyperlink(url,text)` function. However, I don't want to have to create a new table to insert a hyperlink.

I used Applescript Numbers Dictionary to find any reference to hyperlink for iWork containers but couldn't find any.

Comment: I don't think that there is any direct applescript control over this function. If you can select the desired text, your script could add a keystroke (command-k) which will pop up the link widget and enter the link there with a paste.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same idea and found a solution that works for me using this same method. I'm gonna post it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found implies manipulating Numbers UI by sending keystrokes to the application to create the link.

```
tell application "Numbers"
    set myDocument to open POSIX file "/path/to/my/doc.numbers"
    tell myDocument
        activate -- required in order to receive keystrokes in Numbers
        tell sheet 1
            set myText to make text item
            set object text of myText to "Hello World"
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "a" using command down -- select all the text
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "k" using command down -- add a link
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "https://mylink" -- input the link
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke return using command down -- close the link dialog box
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```